# Создание профиля пользователя одновременно с самим пользователем

Tags: python, orm, django

Добрый день!

У меня есть модель, описывающая профиль пользователя:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    contact_person = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name = 'контактное лицо')
```

Также есть форма, которые получает все необходимые данные, проверяет их валидность, и передаёт представлению, которое создаёт нового пользователя:

```
@render_to('registration/new_profile.html')
def new_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = ProfileRegistrationForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            contact_person = form.cleaned_data['contact_person']

            user = User(username, username, password)
            user.save()

            **# Как здесь сохранить соответствующий профиль????**
            **# Как здесь сохранить соответствующий профиль????**
            **# Как здесь сохранить соответствующий профиль????**

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/signup/complete/') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = ProfileForm() # An unbound form

    return  {'form': form,}
```

Как указать профилю, скем он будет связан? Как правильно его сохранить, чтобы ORM правильно сработала? Это возможно сделать в рамках выполнения функции 1 раз?

P.S. User - стандартная имплементация django users

Answer (score 1):

В том месте где Вы указали, просто:

```
profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user, contact_person=username)
```

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону [AutoOneToOneField](http://softwaremaniacs.org/blog/2007/03/07/auto-one-to-one-field/), написанный небезызвестным Иваном Сагалаевым.

Answer (score 1):

Если есть желание почитать чужой код, можете посмотреть вот это http://code.google.com/p/unblog/ - там реализована как встроенная авторизация, так и через Loginza, профиль создается автоматически, в него заносятся данные из профиля в социальной сети. Не образец кода, конечно, но работает.
Про автоматическое создание профиля - [тут](http://code.google.com/p/unblog/source/browse/main/authfuncs.py)
Про автозаполнение полей - [здесь](http://code.google.com/p/unblog/source/browse/main/models.py#28)

Answer (score 0):

```
profile = Profile()
profile.user = user
profile.save()
```